# Value assignment between Series using .loc, same size with different indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue where I have two series of equal size but with different indices. I want to set one series equal to the other. This can be done by resetting the index, but in this case, I am using `.loc` to slice a DataFrame to a Series.

#### Setup

Let's say I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], \
               'num':  [1, 1, 2, 2], \
               'val':  None})

  name  num   val
0    a    1  None
1    b    1  None
2    a    2  None
3    b    2  None
```

And two Series with values:

```
vals_a = pd.Series([21,32])
vals_b = pd.Series([43,54])
```

#### Desired Outcome

```
  name  num   val  vals
0    a    1  None  21.0
1    b    1  None  43.0
2    a    2  None  32.0
3    b    2  None  54.0
```

#### My Code

```
df.loc[df.name == 'a', 'vals'] = vals_a
df.loc[df.name == 'b', 'vals'] = vals_b

  name  num   val  vals
0    a    1  None  21.0
1    b    1  None  54.0
2    a    2  None   NaN
3    b    2  None   NaN
```

This is a simplified version of my problem. In reality, `vals_a` and `vals_b` are slices of a separate DataFrame with variable indices. How do I slice this so my original DataFrame stores the values in the smaller Series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas` is `index` sensitive , which means when you `assign` , beside the condition you mentioned within the `loc` , it will still check the `index` match or not

```
df.loc[df.name == 'a', 'vals'] = vals_a.values
df.loc[df.name == 'b', 'vals'] = vals_b.values
df
Out[964]: 
  name  num   val  vals
0    a    1  None  21.0
1    b    1  None  43.0
2    a    2  None  32.0
3    b    2  None  54.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method I can think of is to use `map` with a dict of iterators:

```
iter_a, iter_b = (iter(v) for v in (vals_a, vals_b))

mapping = {'a': iter_a, 'b': iter_b}
df['name'].map(lambda x: next(mapping[x]))

0    21
1    43
2    32
3    54
Name: name, dtype: int64
```